# Database design for optional parameters

Tags: django, database-design, django-models

I have this model:

```
class Floor(models.Model):
        label = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=100)

class Area(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(null=False, blank=True, max_length=100)
    floor = models.ForeignKey(Floor)

class Room(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(null=False, blank=True, max_length=100)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area)
```

Sometimes, it is OK if a room is not set to a particular area of the floor.

Then, I'm considering two options.

Option 1: I keep this data structure and I create a "label=default" area when the area is not specified.

Option 2: I change to this model:

```
class Floor(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=100)

class Area(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(null=False, blank=True, max_length=100)
    floor = models.ForeignKey(Floor)

class Room(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(null=False, blank=True, max_length=100)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area, null=True)
    floor = models.ForeignKey(Floor)
```

Both options seem ok, but what would be your pro/con advise?

Comment: can you not just enforce that every room must have a floor? I don't know a single building ever built that didn't have a ground/first floor

Answer (score 0):

How can a building not have a floor? I would give  every building at least 1 floor and use the first option.

Because in option 2 you'll have redundant FK's to Building (both for Room and Floor)

Comment: see new edit: I changed Floor to Area, it's more realistic. Small floors doesn't need to have separate areas, but large floors do.